# Syncing Audio and Video

Tags: video-editor, video-recording, video-capture, canon, audio-recording

I have am doing a video recording podcast.

I am recording the audio with Audacity with my 4 Shure mics hooked up into my Clarett 4pre USB.

I am recording the video with OBS Studio a Cannon Vixia GF 40.

I plan on editing the audio and video in Premiere Pro. But I am worried about having it synced up and staying synced.  Any ideas?

What hz should I use for audio?

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand if you intend to transmit live or not. Because you are using OBS which sounds like you want to go live, but at the same time you say you want to use Premiere to edit, which sounds like you want to edit and then publish.

If you want to record, edit and then publish, probably the best option is letting the Vixia camera record live audio and use it as a reference for Premiere to detect some of it and automatically [sync with the new audio track](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/synchronizing-audio-video-merge-clips.html).

If you are recording live, OBS has one feature to synk the delayed audio or video. Search "OBS Audio delay"

---

Regarding the question of the frequency... it depends on several factors. The main factor is output format+platform.

For example, [Youtube recommends](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6039860?hl=en) 44.1 kHz 24 bits for music videos. But accept 48 and 96 kHz.

There is some debate if 96kHz is even perceptible for humans or not.

Comment: I am not going to transmit live. I am going to use OBS so I can easily switch between  video sources (camera most of the time, and screen record partial). There will be occasions in the podcast where I have to pull up a screen whenever the host ask me to pull up sources. OBS seems like the simple way to do this. 

But I am not tied to OBS, but I prefer not to purchase anymore equipment. Also, it is possible to mute the audio from the Vixia camera so the video? 

The reason why I was asking for the rate is because I heard if it isn't at the proper bitrate, it can drift in and out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

- Press once the record button to start recording. Clap 3 to 5 times.
- Import both video and audio into Premiere.
- Align the peaks in the audio of when you were clapping.
- Once you've done that, mute the audio that comes with video, and only enable audio that you've recorded separately.

I've also paid $200 or so for pluraleyes.
The way you use this is that you drag and drop all your files into it's interface.

Once you “synchronize”, press the export timeline button and export the XML file.   This file is essentially going to become your Premiere pro Project.

Voila. Done deal! :)

Answer (score 0):

Recording hz doesn't really matter in this instance, but it's best if your sources match, so make sure they're both set to either 44.1 or 48. There is a built-in automated audio syncing option in Premiere, so it's very easy to sync when editing.

Here's your whole workflow:

1. Make sure you're recording audio on both interfaces, so both Audacity and your camera's built-in mic through OBS.
2. Drag the OBS video and audio to the Premiere timeline.
3. Drag the Audacity audio below the OBS audio on audio track 2.
4. Select all of the imported audio in the timeline.
5. Right-click and select `Synchronize`
6. Select the `Audio` radio button and select `1` in the `Track Channel` fly-out menu. This will sync your audio.
7. Either mute or delete the audio from the camera that you don't want and start editing.
   [image]

One note, if you pause or take a break during your recording, do NOT pause Audacity. Just stop the recording and export a separate file for each stop/start. If you pause, additional audio will just be appended to the first part of your Audacity recording out of sync and you won't be able to sync in Premiere with this method. Additionally, Premiere only lets you sync one item on each track at a time, so if you end up with several recordings from audacity, you'll need to spread them across track 2, track 3 etc. for syncing. You can sync any number of tracks with this method.